# Add SearchBox component to the Home page

Tags: vue.js, search-box, vuepress, vuepress2

I am new the Vuepress and there's very little resources online. I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75810574/vuepress-add-search-component) but hasn't been answer yet.

I am using the [Vuepress boiltertemplate](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/getting-started.html#quick-start) and basically I just want to add the SearchBox component to the home '/'.

According to the [docs](https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/reference/plugin/search.html#searchbox), I can use the <SearchBox /> component globally. I couldn't find a resource anywhere so I don't know where exactly to put it.

The current directory structure is:

├── src

│   ├── .vuepress

│   │   ├── components

│   │   │   ├── Foo

│   │   │   │   ├── Bar

│   │   │   ├── demo-component.vue

│   │   │   ├── OtherComponent.vue

│   │   ├── styles

│   │   │   ├── index.styl

│   │   │   ├── palette.styl

│   │   ├── config.js

│   │   ├── enhanceApp.js

│   ├── confi

│   │   ├── README.md

│   ├── guide

│   │   ├── README.md

│   │   ├── using-vue

│   ├── index.md

├── public

│   ├── css

│   │   ├── **/*.css

│   ├── images

│   ├── js

│   ├── index.html

├── node_modules

├── package.json

├── package-lock.json

└── .gitignore

I tried creating a SearchBox.vue component and added to the config.js using globalLayout but I get errors like these:

`Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys' Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'`

Comment: "I tried creating a SearchBox.vue component and added to the config.js using globalLayout but I get errors like these:" - what exactly did you try? The question is not constructive at this point. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve